# Can not save session with Vue + Express

Tags: node.js, express, session, vue.js, cors

I have server side with ExpressJS with Vue in frontend. I wanted to save sessions, but I can not do this with Vue frontend. I can not find solution of this/ Server side is:

```
    let express = require('express');

let path = require('path');
let favicon = require('serve-favicon');
let logger = require('morgan');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var session = require('express-session')
// const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express_session);

let index = require('./src/routes/index');
let users = require('./src/routes/users');
let gallery = require('./src/routes/gallery')
let auth = require('./src/routes/auth')
let contacts = require('./src/routes/contacts')
let services = require('./src/routes/services')


let cors = require('cors')

let app = express();

app.use(cors({
   origin:['http://localhost:8080'],
    methods:['GET','POST'],
    credentials: true // enable set cookie
}))


let mongoose = require('mongoose')


let express_session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express_session);




//авторизация
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard',
     resave: false,
     saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStore({
        url: 'mongodb://localhost/studio'
    })
}))



let mongoDB = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/studio';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
    useMongoClient: true
});

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


//app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/gallery', gallery );
app.use('/contacts', contacts );
app.use('/auth', auth);
app.use('/services', services );


//Авторизация в данной система


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});


// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

//app.listen(3002);


module.exports = app;
```

I save sessions in mongoose, and when i check server side session is working. But when I want to save session in Vue side it does not working. I think it was because of cors, but it did not help.
 Code of vue here:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <h2>Essential Links</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://vuejs.org" target="_blank">Core Docs</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://forum.vuejs.org" target="_blank">Forum</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://chat.vuejs.org" target="_blank">Community Chat</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/vuejs" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
      <br>
      <li><a href="http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/" target="_blank">Docs for This Template</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
      page_views:undefined,
    }
  },
  beforeMount(){
    this.$http.get("http://localhost:8120/").then((res)=>{
        if(!res.body.session){
          console.log("Session not exist "+res.body.message)
          this.msg = res.body.message;
        }
        else{
          console.log("Session exist "+res.body.page_views)
          this.msg  = res.body.page_views
        }
    },(err)=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

And code of endpoint here is:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

let cors = require('cors')
router.use(cors())

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res){
   if(req.session.page_views){
      req.session.page_views++;
      res.json({session:true,page_views:req.session.page_views});
   } else {
      req.session.page_views = 1;
      res.json({session:false, message:"Welcome to this page for the first time!"})
   }
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: hi,do you still not solve it yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your backend code is ok, you know to set
 `credentials: true // enable set cookie` to avoid the (same origin policy).
But i think it's need for front end to set the credentials too.
you can try this:

```
this.$http.get("http://localhost:8120/", {credentials: true}).then( res => {
   ...do someting 
},(err)=>{
  ... do someting
})
```

it means allow browser to send cookie to back end
good luck!